# ResponsiveSlides.js Page jumps on Android when slide changes

Tags: android

I have implemented a slide show using ResponsiveSlides.js V1.54. I am very impressed with the slideshow but I have found on a Samsung Galaxy Ace phone the page jumps to the top of the page when the slide changes? It works fine on all other devices I have been able to test the slideshow on.
I have a development version of my slideshow at:
http://brixhamgigclub.co.uk/multimedia-new.php?id=9
my js is in the head section of the html

Any ideas to fix this would be appreciated.
Bob

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this problem by methodically removing bits of my code. It appears there maybe contention with the Google Translate code used on my site.
I have removed the meta statement

and the html

```
<div id="googleTranslate">
<div id="google_translate_element"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
function googleTranslateElementInit() {
new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: 'en', includedLanguages:    'bg,cs,cy,da,de,el,en,es,et,fi,fr,ga,hr,hu,it,lt,nl,no,pl,pt,ru,sk,sl,sr,sv', layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.HORIZONTAL}, 'google_translate_element');
 }
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//translate.google.com/translate_a /element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit">
</script>
</div>
```

and problem resolves.
Bob